# reg ex in javascript to allow a specific phone number format (123) 456-7890 only

Tags: javascript, regex

I currently have a function to validate a phone number. This info gets entered in a web app. It is later displayed in a windows app, and that's where the issue comes. I have a specific function that populates data to controls, but it only accepts one type of phone number format and that is

> (123) 456-7890

This is the function we've been using, but it lets the user enter any format as long as it's 10 digits, so it can be something like 123-45-6789

```
function validatePhone(fld) {
    var error = "";
    var stripped = fld.value.replace(/[\(\)\.\-\ ]/g, '');     

   if (fld.value == "") {
        return false;
    } else if (isNaN(parseInt(stripped))) {
        return false;
    } else if (!(stripped.length == 10)) {
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
}
```

I've looked through the web and usually they have a specific reg ex for 2 formats `(123) 456-7890 | 123-456-7890` and the reg ex is (((\d{3}) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4} however in my case I can only allow 1 format (with paranthesis)
Any way to change this so it can validate whether the phone number is in the exact format as I showed above? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following regex

```js
let regex = /^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}$/
console.log(regex.test("(123) 456-7890")) // true
console.log(regex.test("123-456-7890")) //false
```

Comment: @ııı i didn't copied your answer dude. Why do you think every one copy your answer.

Comment: This is actually better than the accepted answer because of the boundaries `^$`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below RegExp to validate the phone number

```js
const valid = "(123) 456-7890";
const invalid = "1234567890";
const re = /^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}$/;
console.log(
  re.test(valid),
  re.test(invalid)
);
```

Comment: actually due to some network problem I was unable to see your post didn't get updated and your initial answer was wrong so I thought I would give my own answer. You answer by wrong but I didn't downvoted. Your initial answer was this `/(\d{3}) \d{3}-\d{4}/.test(fld.value)`

Comment: Your regex says that "1234(123) 456-7890" is valid.